# Invalid argument: url

Tags: url

I wrote my program to search people in an address book. The program will debug fine but will throw an error when I run the application by visiting the link. I have tried different ways and spent too many days but cant figured out why I get this error.

> Link to application : http://goo.gl/k0psKc link to run application :
>   http://goo.gl/xHR18J

Here is my program:

```
**function doGet() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10sd_ZPASWUcmN_9pBy-x1P8Jv06ZVA0Ah-nbLwGa93s/edit#gid=1173191351");
var data = ss.getDataRange(); 
var namefilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build(); var tablechart = Charts.newTableChart() .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,2])).build(); 
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data) .bind([namefilter], [tablechart]).build();
var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
var filterpanel = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
var tablepanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
filterpanel.add(namefilter); tablepanel.add(tablechart).setSpacing(10); dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterpanel).add(tablepanel));
app.add(dashboard); return app; }
```

Comment: You should also state what technologies are involved in your code, and the actual error message being thrown.

Comment: It looks like this is Google Apps Script, but I am not familiar enough with the language to be sure that I should add that tag.